# WebSettings.setZoomLevel "no such method" on Android 2.3

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-websettings

I have the following code (quite simple):

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setTextZoom(110);
```

While running on Android 4.0, all is right. However, both Android 2.2 and Android 2.3.3 throw a "no such method" excepcion when trying to run setTextZoom (the same happens with getTextZoom). I know the previous setTextSize method is now deprecated but I found no info about whether setTextZoom existed back then. I know that my minSdkVersion is 8 and my target is 9 and Eclipse doesn't complain about setTextZoom.

While I could use setTextSize (now deprecated) I find NORMAL size too small and LARGE too big.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This should be supporting new and older APIs.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void updateTextSize(WebSettings settings) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            settings.setTextZoom(some_value);
        } else {
            settings.setTextSize(TextSize.????);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Considering that your real problem is not accessing deprecated APIs, but rather the font size, I believe below is the answer you need:

```
protected void updateTextSize(WebSettings settings, int fontSize) {
        if(fontSize > 1 && fontSize < 72) {
            // there's no point setting a different value considering outside values will be pinned 
            settings.setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I do know now that setTextZoom was introduced in API 14 so no wonder it wasn't working. I'm still looking for a way to have text inbetween NORMAL and LARGE in older APIs.

Comment: Not really, I appreciate your help but what I intend to do is to increase/decrease textSize in a WebView for Android 2.3 with more accuracy than setTextSize allows for.

Comment: Then why weren't you concise in what is your real problem when you posted the question? I'll edit my answer shortly ...

Comment: I did... my two last sentences explain that setTextSize is too imprecise for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @gunar no worries.  People don't accept answers for various befuddling reasons.  Your answer is good.  I'm sure you'll get a good number of upvotes as time goes on.

Comment: I'm not a hunter for accepted answers :) ... just that it makes me feel good when I know for sure that my answer really helped